# Getting syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, ms-access

So I'm receiving this problem, I tried everything. Kinda stuck

My access database design:

```
ID - AutoNumber
Data - ShortText
```

And the insert command:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

string sql = "INSERT INTO Table (Data) VALUES (@Data)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", "Test");

connection.Open();

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("err: " + ex);
    throw;
}

connection.Close();
```

This might be dumb but I'm really lost and I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TABLE` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335) so you should change it's name or you should enclose it in square brackets like `[Table]`:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [Table] (Data) VALUES (@Data)";
```