# Syntax for UPDATE statement with parameters?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Here's the working SQL Statement:

```
DECLARE @LayOdds DEC = 1.5
DECLARE @Umarketiduselectionid VARCHAR(50) = '1.12677402748783'

UPDATE [dbo].[Fixtures]
SET [Fixtures].[Percent] = [Fixtures].[BackOdds] / @LayOdds * 100 - 100
WHERE [Fixtures].[MarketSelectionId] = @Umarketiduselectionid
```

Here's my incorrect C# Statement:

```
string sql = "Update Fixtures SET Percent = BackOdds / @LayOdds * 100 - 100 WHERE MarketSelectionId = @Umarketiduselectionid";

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LayOdds", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = layOdds;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Umarketiduselectionid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = umarketiduselectionid;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Getting  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Percent'.

Comment: `Percent` is a reserved word.  Try `[Percent]`.

Comment: Why are you passing in numeric values as a string?

Comment: Thank you Jim - worked beautifully. Had a feeling when I defined that column as 'Percent' that it might conflict somewhere along the line lool.

Spotted that and edited just as you were commenting Gordon.

Comment: What's the protocol here guys? Shall I answer it with your resolution, Jim, or delete the question?

Comment: You can just leave it as it stands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting syntax error in INSERT INTO statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640847/getting-syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided kindly by Jim Hewitt above. Many thanks.

Percent is a reserved word. Try [Percent].